# In JavaScript what's the difference between Equal to ('==' & '===')

Tags: javascript, html, equality

I am trying to understand equality in JavaScript. Here is the code.

```
    var x = prompt("What is 10 + 10");
    if (x === 10) {
        document.write("Correct")
    }
    else {
        document.write("Incorrect")
    }
```

Why wouldn't I make the equals sign like "===". So if "10" is equal("===") to "x"(user answer) then it should be correct right?

I searched on both Stack Overflow and W3Schools, but couldn't find what I was looking for. I guess I'm just nor getting this "true or false" thing. I mean this seems like a very simple equation. Help would be great thanks guys!

Comment: A prompt returns a string, and you're comparing agains a number. If you do strict comparison (three equal signs), the type will be checked as well, so type number and type string will not be equal, but if you use non-strict comparison (two equal signs) it won't check the type and `10 == "10"` etc

Comment: I disagree because the other questions doesn't EXACTLY explain in detail to detail what I need I wanted a simple answer to a simple equation and most questions and answers Ive read don't make sense to me. Or have Ridiculously complicated answers. I figured asking something simple that I understand the answer would be clearer to me.

Comment: Thanks, I just get tired of these crazy answers that make no sense and the Moderators up people backs all the time I get your trying to get rid of certain stuff. But someone like me I want an answer not a bunch of edits and whatnot you know... and I see it a lot....

Answer (score 5):

`===` is strict type equality which compares by both value and type

`==` is non-strict type equality, which compares only by value.

In other words, `==` performs type conversion and then compares values for equality. Here are some examples

```
"3" == 3
=> true
```

Explanation: The string 3 is converted to the number 3, which is equal to 3.

```
"3" === 3
=> false
```

Explanation: The string is not converted to a number. Thus the string 3 does not equal the number 3.

In your example, `incorrect` would be written to the document. That is because the result of `prompt` returns a string, and you are performing strict equality with a number.

In your case, the interpreter sees it like this

```
if ("10" === 10) {
    // does the string "10" equal the number 10? If so
    document.write("Correct")
}
else {
    // Hey, wait a minute. It doesn't equal the number. I should write "Incorrect" instead.
    document.write("Incorrect")
}
```

Comment: So what your saying is that "===" is for a specific type like a string not a number?

Comment: No. For `===`, no automatic type conversion is performed, so it compares both the value AND type. In other words, this one cares about the type you use. `==` only cares about the value

Comment: OHHH i see thanks GREAT answer.. simple and understood thank you sir have a great day. Happy Holidays!

Comment: Something else I dont get is that === reads specific things like strings, but if i dont use the quotation and just put a number like 10 then why would it read it as a string not a number?

Comment: The prompt method returns a String. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript,

`==` means: *is equivalent to*

`===` means: *is identical to*

When the value of `x` is `"10"`, `x` is equivalent to `10`.

But it *isn't* identical to `10`.

Comment: Thanks that makes good sense!